# GetThreadTimes( ) returning 0 (zero) as the kernel and user time for all the threads

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I was trying to get CPU utilization for particular thread by using `GetThreadTimes`, however for all threads kernel and user time getting equated to zero.

Note:thread is getting created by `_beginthreadex`.

```
(dThreadID->hThread = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, 0,
    (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)threadFunc, threadParam, 0,
    &(dThreadID->threadID));)
```

is this case anything to do with security attributes of `_beginthreadex`?

Please let me know how to resolve this case.

Thanks in advance

Code:
I am calling this inside a static function so pasting the same.

```
threadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
curThread = GetCurrentThread();
GetThreadTimes(curThread, &ftCreation, &ftExit, &ftKernel, &ftUser);
GetSystemTimes(&ftidle, &ftKernelCpu, &ftUserCpu);

ftSysKernelDiff = SubtractTimes(&ftKernelCpu, &ftKernelCpu_old);
ftSysUserDiff = SubtractTimes(&ftUserCpu, &ftUserCpu_old);

ftProcKernelDiff =SubtractTimes(&ftKernel, &ftKernel_old);
ftProcUserDiff =SubtractTimes(&ftUser, &ftUser_old);

nTotalSys =  ftSysKernelDiff + ftSysUserDiff;
nTotalProc = ftProcKernelDiff + ftProcUserDiff;

nCpuUsage = (short)((100.0 * nTotalProc) / nTotalSys);
```

Comment: Please include the code where you call `GetThreadTimes`.

Comment: This is pretty normal, the precision of the returned times is not very good.  Time measurement is based on the clock interrupt rate, it ticks 64 times per second by default.  So the only thing you know is that the thread took less than 15.625 msec.  You can get a *much* higher precision with QueryThreadCycleTime().  But it returns cycles, not time.

Comment: Hans Passant Thanks for info ,So is there any way to get the required time ??